# Convert Date to TimeStamp with TimeZone of postgres

Tags: java, spring, date, time

I have postgresql time column with type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` having a sample value like `1970-01-01 00:00:00+05:30` I want to compare a value
with `Date` value like:

```
Date date = new Date(0L);
```

i.e. Tue Jan 19 13:55:24 IST 2016

So  I used

```
Timestamp timeStampDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

The above code gives timeStampDate.getTime() as 0.

How to convert it in the above format so that it can be compared, Currently comparing is giving no results.
How to format this date.

I basically want to convert " Date is Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970 " to this format : "1970-01-01 00:00:00+05:30"

Comment: The code looks like Java - there is no SQL involved here. Do you want a Java solution or a SQL solution?

Comment: I just need a java solution . I m using SpringDataJpa to query with database later.

Comment: Show what the PostgreSQL value looks like in Java. How do you fetch the data? Do you store the DB value in a String?

Comment: In this kind of Question, you should be *very* explicit about java.util.Date versus java.sql.Date/.Timestamp.

Comment: Why do you want to compare some Date object to a `Date(0L)` object? Your Question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

If your database driver supports JDBC 4.2 or later, use `Instant` to get data from your database where stored in a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

For an older JDBC driver, use [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) to get data from your database by calling `getTimestamp` on your `ResultSet`. That Timestamp object is in UTC. Postgres stores your `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` in UTC, by the way, and loses the original time zone or offset-from-UTC that came with the incoming data after using that data to adjust into UTC as part of the storage process.

You should convert your java.sql.Timestamp/.Date/.Time to java.time types as soon as possible. Then proceed with your business logic.

In a nutshell, java.time is… An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC. Apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

### Convert To java.time

So convert from Timestamp, get an Instant, apply a ZoneId.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = myResultSet.getTimestamp( 1 );
…
Instant instant = ts.toInstant();
```

Specify your desired/expected time zone. Apply to the Instant.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

### Comparison

Get the current moment, for use in comparison.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
```

Compare by calling the `isEqual`, `isBefore`, or `isAfter` methods.

```
Boolean beforeNow = zdt.isBefore( now );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).